# Login page that gives error messages and submits to self

Tags: php, mysql, forms, authentication

im currently stuck trying to create a log in form that submits to its self so that if theres any errors they'll be displayed above the login form rather than being sent to another page. Also if the login is successful then they're sent to the desired page. Here's my code below, I appreciate any help, Thanks!

```
<?php
if ((isset($_REQUEST['username'])) && (isset($_REQUEST['password']))) {
    $adminusername = $_POST["username"];
    $adminpassword = $_POST["password"];
    if ($adminusername == '' || $adminpassword == '') {
        echo "<b>You must complete all sections</b><br/>";
    } 

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username = '$adminusername' AND password = '$adminpassword'");

    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
    if ($numrows != 0) {

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
            $dbusername = $row['username'];
            $dbpassword = $row['password'];
        }             

        if ($adminusername == $dbusername && ($adminpassword == $dbpassword)) {
            $_SESSION['username'] = $adminusername;
            header("Location: admin.php");
        }
    } else {
        echo " ($error) Username and password do not match";
    }                 
}
?>
<h3>Admin Login</h3>
<form name="login" action="<?= $SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="POST">
    Username: <input type="text" name="username"><br/>
    Password: <input type="password" name="password"><br/><br/>
    <button type="submit">Log In</button>
</form>
```

Comment: What are you stuck with? What is it doing, that it shouldn't? Or what isn't it doing, that it should?

Comment: and your problem is...? Other than the [sql injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) holes, of course.

Comment: When i enter the correct information that should send me to the admin page, nothing happens, no error information - nothing. If the information is correct it should redirect to the admin area...

Comment: You haven't started or set a session yet you refer to it.

Comment: not sure of function name look it u but before sending any string or user data to db must xcheck and escape it or risk sql injection. mysql_real_escape .....

Comment: i'm not massively worried about sql injection attacks at the minute its just a school project - i'd just like the login to work first. I'll have a read up about it though.

Comment: When you say "nothing happens" do you mean that you get a blank screen, or just that you go back to the form?

Comment: @op username: `hacker' or 1=1 limit 1--` will login for the first user. Changing the limit anyone can log in as any user. If they know the username then `username'--` will login as him. So use proper validation. @tgkprog your given function will not prevent sql injection here. I do not know how to exploit it but i saw a chellange in wechall.net about exploiting it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've indented your code so you can see the structure more clearly.

If the username and password are blank then an error will be output, but the database will still be queried.

You're not checking whether the database query actually works.  You should check `$query` is not false, and if it is report an error.

You're checking the username and passwords match twice (once in the SQL and once again later), this is overkill, and besides you're not reporting if the second check fails.

`header()` will only work if you've not sent any output yet... if there's anything output before the code you've shown, even a blank line outside of PHP, then the header won't work.

On its own, this works for me (sql injection potential aside):

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $adminusername = $_POST["username"];
    $adminpassword = $_POST["password"];
    if ($adminusername == '' || $adminpassword == '') {
        echo "<b>You must complete all sections</b><br/>";
    } else {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username = '$adminusername' AND password = '$adminpassword'";
        $query = mysql_query($sql);

        if ($query === false) {
            echo "Could not successfully run query ($sql) from DB: " . mysql_error();
            exit;
        }

        if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0) {
            $_SESSION['username'] = $adminusername;
            header('Location: /admin.php');
            exit;
        }

        echo "<b>Username and password do not match</b><br/>";
    }
}
?>
<h3>Admin Login</h3>
<form name="login" action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="POST">
    Username: <input type="text" name="username"><br/>
    Password: <input type="password" name="password"><br/><br/>
    <button type="submit">Log In</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

To submit a `<form>`, you need a submit button; you've got:

```
<button type="submit">Log In</button>
```

try:

```
<input type="submit" value="Log In" />
```

I don't think you're currently submitting the form, so nothing will happen when you click submit.

Comment: `<button>`s are valid for submitting forms.

Comment: Huh. So they are. I guess that's the new thing I've learned today.

Answer (score 0):

instead of 
     header("Location: admin.php");

try java script

```
echo "<script>window.location = 'admin.php';</script>
```

if you have already outpu to the page header wont work

Comment: But unless errors are not being reported, PHP should inform you that headers have already been sent.

Answer (score 0):

My solution echos the form with the error below it within a `div`. I'm still learning but I hope it helps someone.

```
<div>
  <?php
    //make sure the form action='' is set to itseslf 
echo "
        <form action='self_page_name' method='post'>
          <table>
            <tr>    
              <td>UserName:</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><input type='text' name='username' required='required' /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Password: </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><input type='password' name='password' required='required' /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Login' /></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </form>
     ";
//////////your php validation script here////////////
  ?>
</div>
```

Comment: It is better and usually more rewarding to work on new questions than those that are a year old and have an answer marked already.